# Evaluating an improper integral with the help of WA

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, wolfram-alpha

> Let
>
> $$I = \int_0^\infty\frac{x\sin 3x}{(x^2+16)^2}$$
>
> Find $I$ using complex integration.

My try: We should consider
$$f(z) = \frac{ze^{3iz}}{(z^2+16)^2}$$
Using WA, I found that $\operatorname{res}_{z = -4i} = \frac{-3e^{12}}{16}$ and $\operatorname{res}_{z = 4i} = \frac{3e^{-12}}{16}$. Therefore the value of $I$ should be $\pi (\frac{-3e^{12}}{16} + \frac{3e^{-12}}{16})$ according to the residue theorem but WA gives $I = \frac{3\pi}{16e^{12}}$. What am I missing here? Also I wanted to know other methods for evaluating this integral like differentiation under the integral sign. I tried $\sin \lambda x$ and then differentiate with respect to $\lambda$ but it got messy.

Comment: Which contour did you choose? Remember that you just need to compute the residues inside the contour. I suppose you chose a semicircle in the upper half-plane, right? So, you just need to compute the $res_{z=4i}$, which will lead to the same answer as WA.

Comment: @TeruoUchida That's right, thanks a lot. Do you know other methods for evaluating that integral?

Comment: I will think about it and try to come up with something else. But I think that we might be able to use Differentiation Under the Integral Sign if with use $cos(\lambda x)$ instead of sine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that mix Residue Theorem and Differentiation Under the Integral Sign. 
First, let's consider the following function:
$$F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos (\alpha z)}{z^2+\beta^2}dz=\frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{R}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{i\alpha z}}{z^2+\beta^2}dz\right)=\frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{R}\left(2\pi i \frac{e^{-\alpha\beta}}{2\beta i} \right)$$

$$F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos (\alpha z)}{z^2+\beta^2}dz=\frac{\pi}{2\beta }e^{-\alpha\beta}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2F(\alpha,\beta)}{\partial\alpha\partial\beta}=2\beta\int_0^\infty\frac{z\sin (\alpha z)}{(z^2+\beta^2)^2}dz=\frac{\pi\alpha}{2 }e^{-\alpha\beta}$$

Another approach using only Differentiation Under the Integral Sign:
$$F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (\alpha z)}{z(z^2+\beta^2)}dz=\frac{1}{\beta^2}\int_0^\infty \underbrace{\frac{\sin (\alpha z)}{z}dz}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\frac{1}{\beta^2}\int_0^\infty \underbrace{-\frac{z\sin (\alpha z)}{z^2+\beta^2}dz}_{\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial \alpha^2}}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 F(\alpha,\beta)}{\partial \alpha^2}-\beta^2 F(\alpha,\beta)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$F_c(\alpha,\beta)=c_1e^{\alpha\beta}+c_2e^{-\alpha\beta}$$

$$F_p=(\alpha,\beta)=-e^{\alpha\beta}\int\frac{-\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\alpha\beta}}{W(e^{\alpha\beta},e^{-\alpha\beta})}d\alpha+e^{-\alpha\beta}\int\frac{-\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\alpha\beta}}{W(e^{\alpha\beta},e^{-\alpha\beta})}d\alpha$$

$$F_p=(\alpha,\beta)=-\frac{\pi e^{\alpha\beta}}{4\beta}\int e^{-\alpha\beta}d\alpha+\frac{\pi e^{-\alpha\beta}}{4\beta}\int e^{\alpha\beta}d\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2 \beta^2}$$

Therefore:
$$F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (\alpha z)}{z(z^2+\beta^2)}dz=c_1e^{\alpha\beta}+c_2e^{-\alpha\beta}+\frac{\pi}{2 \beta^2}$$

$$F(0,\beta)=0=c_1+c_2+\frac{\pi}{2 \beta^2};\frac{\partial F(0,\beta)}{\partial\alpha}=\frac{\pi}{2\beta}=\beta(c_1-c_2)$$

Thus:
$$F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (\alpha z)}{z(z^2+\beta^2)}dz=-\frac{\pi}{2 \beta^2}e^{-\alpha\beta}+\frac{\pi}{2 \beta^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial^3F(\alpha,\beta)}{\partial\alpha^2\partial\beta}=2\beta\int_0^\infty\frac{z\sin (\alpha z)}{(z^2+\beta^2)^2}dz=\frac{\pi\alpha}{2 }e^{-\alpha\beta}$$

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome :)